# Creating email templates with Django

Tags: django, email, django-email, django-mailer

I want to send HTML-emails, using Django templates like this:

```
<html>
<body>
hello <strong>{{username}}</strong>
your account activated.
<img src="mysite.com/logo.gif" />
</body>
```

I can't find anything about `send_mail`, and django-mailer only sends HTML templates, without dynamic data.

How do I use Django's template engine to generate e-mails?

Comment: Notice Django `1.7` offers `html_message` in `send_email` http://stackoverflow.com/a/28476681/953553

Comment: Hi @anakin, I have struggled with this problem for a long time and decided to create a package for that. I would be very happy to get your feedback : https://github.com/charlesthk/django-simple-mail

Answer (score 440, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types), to send HTML e-mail you want to use alternative content-types, like this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

You'll probably want two templates for your e-mail - a plain text one that looks something like this, stored in your templates directory under `email.txt`:

```
Hello {{ username }} - your account is activated.
```

and an HTMLy one, stored under `email.html`:

```
Hello <strong>{{ username }}</strong> - your account is activated.
```

You can then send an e-mail using both those templates by making use of [`get_template`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loader.get_template), like this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

plaintext = get_template('email.txt')
htmly     = get_template('email.html')

d = Context({ 'username': username })

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = plaintext.render(d)
html_content = htmly.render(d)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Comment: I think you can simplify this with [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut), which would let you lose the separate lines assigning templates to `plaintext` and `htmly`, and just set templates and contexts when you define `text_content` and `html_content`.

Comment: @cms_mgr Can you elaborate what you want to say and how we can use that

Comment: @akki see andi's answer below, which also simplifies the alternative part thanks to html_message param being added to send_email() in Django 1.7

Comment: Pardon me but why do we use txt and htmly both at the same time for a mail. I didnt get this logic

Comment: they are just examples to show different kind of methods, you can use any of the them @ShashankVivek

Comment: Some old mail clients do not support HTML mail, so they will show the plain text version. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Nowadays context should only be a dict.
So instead of d = Context({...}), d = {...} is the correct way ;)

Comment: @Hafnernuss answer applies for 2021's Django `3.1.5` with python `3.8.5`. No need to `from django.template import Context`. Just do `d = { 'username': username }`.

Answer (score 311):

Since Django's 1.7 in [send_email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) method the `html_message` parameter was added.

> html_message: If html_message is provided, the resulting email will be
> a multipart/alternative email with message as the text/plain content
> type and html_message as the text/html content type.

So you can just:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


msg_plain = render_to_string('templates/email.txt', {'some_params': some_params})
msg_html = render_to_string('templates/email.html', {'some_params': some_params})

send_mail(
    'email title',
    msg_plain,
    'some@sender.com',
    ['some@receiver.com'],
    html_message=msg_html,
)
```

Comment: Note if 'email.txt' and 'email.html' are in a directory templates as defined in settings than just do render_to_string('email.txt', {'some_params': some_params}_

Comment: Good solution! However, with `send_mail` is not possible to set some custom header like i.e `Return-Path` which can be set with the `EmailMultiAlternatives's constructor header parameter`

Comment: 'templates' needs to be removed from the file name in (at least in python 3.8) otherwise it yields a `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist` error.  

by default path is relative to the templates folder

Answer (score 28):

I have made [django-templated-email](https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email) in an effort to solve this problem, inspired by this solution (and the need to, at some point, switch from using django templates to using a mailchimp etc. set of templates for transactional, templated emails for my own project). It is still a work-in-progress though, but for the example above, you would do:

```
from templated_email import send_templated_mail
send_templated_mail(
        'email',
        'from@example.com',
        ['to@example.com'],
        { 'username':username }
    )
```

With the addition of the following to settings.py (to complete the example):

```
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_DJANGO_SUBJECTS = {'email':'hello',}
```

This will automatically look for templates named 'templated_email/email.txt' and 'templated_email/email.html' for the plain and html parts respectively, in the normal django template dirs/loaders (complaining if it cannot find at least one of those).

Comment: Looks good to me.  I've trimmed this down and thrown it into a ticket to add `django.shortcuts.send_templated_mail`: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17193

Comment: Cool, glad to see it get proposed as a tool for django core. My use-case/focus for the lib is a bit bigger than just the shortcut, (easy switching between mail providers that have key/value api's for mail sending), but it does feel like a missing feature from core

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old question, but I also know that **some people are just like me and are always looking for uptodate answers**, since old answers can sometimes have deprecated information if not updated.

**Its now January 2020, and I am using Django 2.2.6 and Python 3.7**

*Note: I use [DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), the code below for sending email was in a [model viewset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) in my `views.py`*

So after reading multiple nice answers, this is what I did.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def send_receipt_to_email(self, request):

    emailSubject = "Subject"
    emailOfSender = "email@domain.com"
    emailOfRecipient = 'xyz@domain.com'

    context = ({"name": "Gilbert"}) #Note I used a normal tuple instead of  Context({"username": "Gilbert"}) because Context is deprecated. When I used Context, I got an error > TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context

    text_content = render_to_string('receipt_email.txt', context, request=request)
    html_content = render_to_string('receipt_email.html', context, request=request)

    try:
        #I used EmailMultiAlternatives because I wanted to send both text and html
        emailMessage = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=emailSubject, body=text_content, from_email=emailOfSender, to=[emailOfRecipient,], reply_to=[emailOfSender,])
        emailMessage.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        emailMessage.send(fail_silently=False)

    except SMTPException as e:
        print('There was an error sending an email: ', e) 
        error = {'message': ",".join(e.args) if len(e.args) > 0 else 'Unknown Error'}
        raise serializers.ValidationError(error)
```

**Important!** So how does `render_to_string` get `receipt_email.txt` and `receipt_email.html`?
In my `settings.py`, I have `TEMPLATES` and below is how it looks

Pay attention to `DIRS`, there is this line `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'email_templates')`
.This line is what makes my templates accessible. In my project_dir, I have a folder called `templates`, and a sub_directory called `email_templates` like this `project_dir->templates->email_templates`. My templates `receipt_email.txt` and `receipt_email.html` are under the `email_templates` sub_directory.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'email_templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Let me just add that, my `recept_email.txt` looks like this;

```
Dear {{name}},
Here is the text version of the email from template
```

And, my `receipt_email.html` looks like this;

```
Dear {{name}},
<h1>Now here is the html version of the email from the template</h1>
```

Answer (score 16):

Use EmailMultiAlternatives and render_to_string to make use of two alternative templates (one in plain text and one in html):

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

c = Context({'username': username})    
text_content = render_to_string('mail/email.txt', c)
html_content = render_to_string('mail/email.html', c)

email = EmailMultiAlternatives('Subject', text_content)
email.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
email.to = ['to@example.com']
email.send()
```

Answer (score 7):

I have created [Django Simple Mail](https://github.com/charlesthk/django-simple-mail) to have a simple, customizable and reusable template for every transactional email you would like to send.

Emails contents and templates can be edited directly from django's admin.

With your example, you would register your email :

```
from simple_mail.mailer import BaseSimpleMail, simple_mailer


class WelcomeMail(BaseSimpleMail):
    email_key = 'welcome'

    def set_context(self, user_id, welcome_link):
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        return {
            'user': user,
            'welcome_link': welcome_link
        }


simple_mailer.register(WelcomeMail)
```

And send it this way :

```
welcome_mail = WelcomeMail()
welcome_mail.set_context(user_id, welcome_link)
welcome_mail.send(to, from_email=None, bcc=[], connection=None, attachments=[],
                   headers={}, cc=[], reply_to=[], fail_silently=False)
```

I would love to get any feedback.

Comment: It would help a lot if you upload a demo application of your package on your repo.

Comment: Hi @ans2human thanks for this suggestion, I add it to the list of improvements !

Answer (score 4):

`send_emai()` didn't work for me so I used `EmailMessage` [here in django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types).

I have included two versions of the anser:

1. With html email version only
2. With plain text email and html email versions

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string 
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

# import file with html content
html_version = 'path/to/html_version.html'

html_message = render_to_string(html_version, { 'context': context, })

message = EmailMessage(subject, html_message, from_email, [to_email])
message.content_subtype = 'html' # this is required because there is no plain text email version
message.send()
```

If you want to include a plain text version of your email, modify the above like this:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string 
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives # <= EmailMultiAlternatives instead of EmailMessage

plain_version = 'path/to/plain_version.html' # import plain version. No html content
html_version = 'path/to/html_version.html' # import html version. Has html content

plain_message = render_to_string(plain_version, { 'context': context, })
html_message = render_to_string(html_version, { 'context': context, })

message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, plain_message, from_email, [to_email])
message.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html") # attach html version
message.send()
```

My plain and html versions look like this:
plain_version.html:

```
Plain text {{ context }}
```

html_version.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 ...
 </head>
<body>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="320" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse; font-family:  Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.5;">
...
{{ context }}
...
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your first solution worked like a charm for me. I didn't want anything to do with the `txt` file so I've used the `EmailMessage` class. Thanks for this awesome solution mate! :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in the example.... if you use it as written, the following error occurs:

> < type 'exceptions.Exception' >: 'dict' object has no attribute 'render_context'

You will need to add the following import:

```
from django.template import Context
```

and change the dictionary to be:

```
d = Context({ 'username': username })
```

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Answer (score 3):

**[Django Mail Templated](https://github.com/artemrizhov/django-mail-templated)** is a feature-rich Django application to send emails with Django template system.

Installation:

```
pip install django-mail-templated
```

Configuration:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'mail_templated'
)
```

Template:

```
{% block subject %}
Hello {{ user.name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{{ user.name }}, this is the plain text part.
{% endblock %}
```

Python:

```py
from mail_templated import send_mail
send_mail('email/hello.tpl', {'user': user}, from_email, [user.email])
```

More info: https://github.com/artemrizhov/django-mail-templated

Comment: Hi, how can I set all my recipients to BCC?

Comment: @aldesabido This is just a wrapper around the standard EmailMessage class of Django. So you should read the official documentation when looking for such features: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/ Also take a look at similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470172/send-mail-with-python-using-bcc

Comment: To be more precise, the standard EmailMessage is not wrapped, but inherited. I.e. this is extension for the standard class :)

Comment: Possible to include JS/CSS in template?

Comment: Not sure if it will work for most email readers if you insert inline js/css into html body, but this is possible, why not.

Answer (score 0):

I like using this tool to permit easily to send email HTML and TXT with easy context processing: https://github.com/divio/django-emailit

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [snippet](https://blog.anvileight.com/posts/django-email-templates-with-context-stored-in-database/) that allows you to send emails rendered with templates stored in the database. An example:

```
EmailTemplate.send('expense_notification_to_admin', {
    # context object that email template will be rendered with
    'expense': expense_request,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamic email templates for your mail then save the email content in your database tables.
This is what i saved as HTML code in database =

```
<p>Hello.. {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}.  <br> This is an <strong>important</strong> {{ message }}
<br> <b> By Admin.</b>

 <p style='color:red'> Good Day </p>
```

In your views:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template

def dynamic_email(request):
    application_obj = AppDetails.objects.get(id=1)
    subject = 'First Interview Call'
    email = request.user.email
    to_email = application_obj.email
    message = application_obj.message

    text_content = 'This is an important message.'
    d = {'first_name': application_obj.first_name,'message':message}
    htmly = FirstInterviewCall.objects.get(id=1).html_content #this is what i have saved previously in database which i have to send as Email template as mentioned above HTML code

    open("partner/templates/first_interview.html", "w").close() # this is the path of my file partner is the app, Here i am clearing the file content. If file not found it will create one on given path.
    text_file = open("partner/templates/first_interview.html", "w") # opening my file
    text_file.write(htmly) #putting HTML content in file which i saved in DB
    text_file.close() #file close

    htmly = get_template('first_interview.html')
    html_content = htmly.render(d)  
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, email, [to_email])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

This will send the dynamic HTML template what you have save in Db.