# django add html email template

Tags: html, django, email, templates

This code is from django_messages application.Even though template is supposed to be html, i still get raw html code in email body.What needs to be done in this case to send both text version and properly working HTML version?

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}

{% blocktrans with recipient=message.recipient sender=message.sender %}Hello {{ recipient }},

you received a private message from {{ sender }} with
the following contents:{% endblocktrans %}

{{ message.body|safe }}

--
{% blocktrans %}Sent from {{ site_url }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

Above is new_message.html file

Below is actual code for sending email

```
def new_message_email(sender, instance, signal, 
    subject_prefix=_(u'New Message: %(subject)s'),
    template_name="messages/new_message.html",
    default_protocol=None,
    *args, **kwargs):
"""
This function sends an email and is called via Django's signal framework.
Optional arguments:
    ``template_name``: the template to use
    ``subject_prefix``: prefix for the email subject.
    ``default_protocol``: default protocol in site URL passed to template
"""
if default_protocol is None:
    default_protocol = getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL', 'http')

if 'created' in kwargs and kwargs['created']:
    try:
        current_domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        subject = subject_prefix % {'subject': instance.subject}
        message = render_to_string(template_name, {
            'site_url': '%s://%s' % (default_protocol, current_domain),
            'message': instance,
        })

        if instance.recipient.email != "":
            send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                [instance.recipient.email,])
    except Exception as e:
        #print e
        pass #fail silently

if 'created' in kwargs and kwargs['created']:
    try:
        current_domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        subject = subject_prefix % {'subject': instance.subject}
        message = render_to_string(template_name, {
            'site_url': '%s://%s' % (default_protocol, current_domain),
            'message': instance,
        })

        if instance.recipient.email != "":
            send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                [instance.recipient.email,])
    except Exception as e:
        #print e
        pass #fail silently
```

**This is new code i tried by following example but it is not working.**

```
if 'created' in kwargs and kwargs['created']:
    try:
        current_domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        subject = subject_prefix % {'subject': instance.subject}
        html_content = render_to_string(template_name, {
            'site_url': '%s://%s' % (default_protocol, current_domain),
            'message': instance,
        })

        if instance.recipient.email != "":
            text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                [instance.recipient.email,])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            send_mail(msg)
    except Exception as e:
        #print e
        pass #fail silently
```

Comment: I had the same problem but solved it. I posted my result here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62582892/4202997

Answer (score 3):

In Django 1.7+, you can specify `html_message` when using [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#send-mail). The `message` parameter is still required for clients that do not support html emails.

For Django 1.6 and earlier, see the instructions for [sending alternative content types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types). Instead of calling `send_mail`, you construct an email message, set the html content, then send it.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Comment: Aware of html_message but using older version then 1.7+.
I had a look at the link many times  but was not sure how to apply it in this specific code above.

Comment: You just need to replace your `send_mail()` with the example in the docs, and adjust the subject, body etc as required. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Please see original question.At the end i posted new code.

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Remove the try except block while you are writing the code, so that you can see what the problem is, instead of it failing silently.

Comment: This is what i get:
send_mail() takes at least 4 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem :)