# Call a template in html_content in django core email

Tags: django, django-email

How can I call a template instead of plain HTML to send email with django core email?

My views:

```
to = articles.user.email
            html_content = '<p>This is your email content...</p>'
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('You have an email',html_content,'from@server.com',[to])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content,'text/html')
            msg.send()
```

In the variable `html_content` you can see is plain HTML, how can I call here a template? This template would be the content of the email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating email templates with Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547/creating-email-templates-with-django)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the template loader [`get_template`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.get_template) function to load your template:

```
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

my_context = {}
html_content = get_template('mytemplate.html').render(Context(my_context))
```