# Sending professional emails through django

Tags: django, email

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

I want to be able to sends newsletters or emails that have been designed properly, including images if possible. I was wondering if I could change this

```
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
```

into an html template file. Like this

```
html_content = 'newsletter/news.html'
```

If not then how do I go about sending emails like that of Quora and other websites.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating email templates with Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547/creating-email-templates-with-django)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily take any template and turn it into a string, for any purpose including sending mails:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template

template = get_template('newsletter/news.html')
html_content = template.render({pass any context you might need})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly pass a template like that but you can use [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
html_content  = render_to_string('newsletter/news.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
```

However be aware that there are certain limitations in HTML email. For example you can't use javascript. Images may or may not be displayed and external stylesheets cannot be used either.

Comment: Forgot about render_to_string, that saves a line.

Comment: but you got in 5 seconds ahead of me @RemcoGerlich so here is +1 from me

Comment: thanks very much...I tried this and it also worked  html_content = get_template('newsletter/news.html').render()