# How to send an email using email_user containing HTML and CSS in Python Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, html-email

I am sending an activation link to the user on their registered email for my blog. I am using the following lines of code for sending the email in my signup view. I am not using EmailMultiAlternatives or send_email because, I am creating a unique token for the user signing up and I want to use email_user, which will automatically take care of for and to email address:-

```
current_site = get_current_site(request)
subject = 'Activate Your Account'
message = render_to_string('accounts/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
message.content_subtype = "html"
user.email_user(subject, message)
```

I have added html and css in my template account_activation_email.html as under:-

```
{% autoescape off %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Activate your SaralGyaan account</title>

    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    [styles go there not shown due to beverity]
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="preheader">Use this link to activate your SaralGyaan account. The link is only valid for 24 hours.</span>
    <table class="email-wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <table class="email-content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td class="email-masthead">
                <a href="https://saralgyaan.com" class="email-masthead_name">
        SaralGyaan
      </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Email Body -->
            <tr>
              <td class="email-body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <table class="email-body_inner" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <!-- Body content -->
                  <tr>
                    <td class="content-cell">
                      <h1>Hi {{user.get_full_name}},</h1>
                      <p>Thank you for registering your SaralGyaan's account. Please click the link below to activate your account. <strong>This link is only valid for the next 24 hours.</strong></p>
                      <!-- Action -->
                      <table class="body-action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                            <!-- Border based button
                       https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design -->
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>
                                        <a href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}" class="button button--green" target="_blank">Activate your account</a>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <p> If you have not created an account, please ignore this email or <a href="mailto:support@saralgyaan.com">contact support</a> if you have questions.</p>
                      <p>Thanks,
                        <br>The SaralGyaan Team</p>
                      <!-- Sub copy -->
                      <table class="body-sub">
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <p class="sub">If you’re having trouble with the button above, copy and paste the URL below into your web browser.</p>
                            <p class="sub">{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}</p>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table class="email-footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="content-cell" align="center">
                      <p class="sub align-center">&copy; 2018 SaralGyaan. All rights reserved.</p>
                      <p class="sub align-center">
                        [SaralGyaan]
                      </p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the email which I am receiving is not the html version of it but plain text. There is no error in this html code as I am using the same with my password reset email and it is working fine there.

Comment: You can use from django.template.loader import get_template

Comment: I could not figure out how to implement get_template instead of render_to_string with my current code. Can you help me in that?

Comment: I believe you shouldnt face any problem after watching this how to use get_template https://youtu.be/IGE8uhVDd-c?t=500s still if problem persist feel free to ask!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating email templates with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547/creating-email-templates-with-django)

Comment: @ZahidKhan thanks for the link, will look into that. As for now I have implemented the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send HTML alone in an email. HTML is sent as an alternative to plain text.

Use the `html_message` to send the html part and use `message` to send in plain text.

```
message = render_to_string('template.txt', ...)
html_message = render_to_string('textmplate.html', ...)
```

Comment: I tried changing message to html_message and then user.email_user(subject, html_message) it still sent it as plain text.

Comment: @UditHariVashisht Use named parameters in your code. Like `user.email_user(subject=subject, message=message, html_message=html_message)`