# How to send an email with bold string using Django

Tags: django

My Django app sends an email as follows:

```
mail_subject='Hi'
to_email='xyz@gmail.com'
message=render_to_string('app1/xyz.html',{
                    'user':User1,'var1':'BLUE'})
email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send();
```

`xyz.html` looks like below:
I would like for the following string to be bold

```
<strong>{{var1}}</strong>
```

but it just shows as `<strong>BLUE</strong>` in the email. I would like to see **BLUE**

Comment: Did you try to make you 'var1="<strong>blue</strong>"', And then in your template use the '{{var1 | escape}}'

Comment: Or look at this this similar question and answers. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2809547/3140312

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string



msg_html = render_to_string('templates/xyz.html', {'some_params': some_params})

send_mail(
    'email title',
    'Hi',
    'sender@gmail.com',
    ['xyz@gmail.com'],
    html_message=msg_html,
)
```

We can create any structure (bold/italic) in xyz.html and it will display nicely inside an email.