# Python send an email passing variable value to html

Tags: django, python-3.x, html-email

In my project i have to send an email and pass a value into html code.
I try this:

```
l_sender = []
l_sender.append('mario.rossi@test.com')
emailsend(l_sender)

def emailsend(l_sender):
    context = {
        'news': 'We have good news!'
    }


    try:
        send_html_email(l_sender, 'Get started with Aida', 'email.html', context, sender='wepredict@cathedral.ai')
        print("Email send")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

in email.html i insert {{ context.news }} but nothing appen.
How can i pass my news val value in mail.html?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You here *call* `emailsend` *before* it is defined, you should make the `emailsend(l_sender)` *after* the `def emailsend(..)` clause.

Comment: That being said, it might be useful to show (and first inspect yourself) the traceback. Typically this gives already quite relevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why context.news? You must use `{{ news }}`.
The function you called cannot even see that your variable was named `context`.

Look at this examples: [Creating email templates with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547/creating-email-templates-with-django)