# Im trying to send password reset emails in Django but unfortunately its sending plain html which hasn't been covered to string

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

I have customized my Django reset password template but every time I send reset password emails they are sent as html which hasn't been converted into a string
A good example is this

```
        <p>please go to the following page and choose a new password:</p>
        <h5>
        http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/reset/MQ/52b-204bbaf9b94c438dff7e/
        Thanks for using our site!
        </h5>
```

This is how it appears my inbox.
My code is follows:
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', UserCreate.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login', UserLoginAPIView.as_view(), name='login'),
    re_path(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
            activate, name='activate'),
    path('password/reset', PasswordResetView.as_view(),
         {'template_name': 'templates/registration/password_reset_email.html',
          'html_email_template_name': 'templates/registration/password_reset_email.html',
          'subject_template_name': 'templates/registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
          'from_email': config('EMAIL_HOST_USER'),
          'extra_email_context': 'templates/registration/password_reset_email.txt',
          },
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password/reset/done', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
         {'template_name': 'templates/registration/password_reset_done.html'},
         name='password_reset_done'),
    re_path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
            name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

password_reset.html

```
<p>please go to the following page and choose a new password:</p>
<h5>
http://127.0.0.1:8000{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
Thanks for using our site!
</h5>
```

I have done research on how I can convert html to a string with no success

Comment: The name of your template does not match the argument to the `path`.

Comment: What do you mean not convert to string?

Comment: @seuling  I wish to convert the html into a string so that when its sent to it can look like a web template

Answer (score 0):

Django's default email system has the ability to send emails as either text or html. You're probably sending via the text option only.

Check out EmailMultiAlternatives  as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547/creating-email-templates-with-django) SO post.

Also look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/) for the full explanation.

Edit:

from the Docs, to send an html email:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Notice the the "msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

Comment: I think that it's supposed to be converted by Django backend which is sending the email? I really don't understand why its not doing that

Comment: Because your most likely telling Django to send the email as text instead of html.   I'll edit my answer, but you should read the Docs in the link I sent you.