# Inserting a Django URL into a custom email template

Tags: html, django, django-email

I'm trying to send a Django email in a custom template that I made for my site.

However, I can't get the Django URL link to work properly. Without the template, I can get the link to work. The username works for reference.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Here is my **views.py**:

```py
    #This code is in the view that sends the email
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
    from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
    from django.template.loader import get_template
    from django.template import Context

    subject, from_email = 'subject', '<info@mysite.com>'
    plaintext = get_template('email.txt')
    htmly = get_template('email.html')
    username = user.username
    d = { 'username': username }
    text_content = plaintext.render(d)
    html_content = htmly.render(d)            
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [user.email])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

This setup is based on this answer: [Creating email templates with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547/creating-email-templates-with-django)

Here is the email.html file:

```html
    <h3>Hi <strong>{{ username }}</strong>,</h6>
    <p> disown kvdsvnsdov vknvisodvnsdv dsdov siod vsd. Here is a link:</p>
    <a href="http://domain{% url 'home' %}">Check Now</a>
```

Here is the email.txt:

```
    Hi {{ username }},
    disown kvdsvnsdov vknvisodvnsdv dsdov siod vsd. Here is a link:
    http://domain{% url 'home' %}
```

Comment: What error you are getting or any traceback?

Comment: @ParthS007 No error, the email sends. The link is just blank. Nothing shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about your template, but if I remember Django urls correctly, you can use `reverse` in your code and pass the resolved url to your template through context. So it'd be something like this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.urls import reverse

subject, from_email = 'subject', '<info@mysite.com>'
plaintext = get_template('email.txt')
htmly = get_template('email.html')
username = user.username
d = { 'username': username, 'url': reverse('home') }
text_content = plaintext.render(d)
html_content = htmly.render(d)            
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [user.email])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Template:

```
<h3>Hi <strong>{{ username }}</strong>,</h6>
<p> disown kvdsvnsdov vknvisodvnsdv dsdov siod vsd. Here is a link:</p>
<a href="http://domain{{ url }}">Check Now</a>
```

Comment: awesome, let me try this. I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the absolute URL in the link within your email template.

When you send out an email, Django fills in the URL with a relative URL and perhaps your Gmail mail client is filling in URL with its own domain and language prefix path.

You need to add the domain name of your current site from within a Django template.

The `<a>` will look like this:

```py
<a href="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'home' %}">Check Now</a>
```

To render a template for an email, which is one of the cases where you'd want the host value:

```py
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def view(request):
    ...
    email_body = render_to_string(
        'template.txt', context, request=request)
```