# Send filtered data using django via email

Tags: python, django, email, send

i want filter the student data by the skills in the vacancy and then send it to the company who posted the requirements in vacancy via email.does anyone have idea about this.

** The Model**

```
class Student(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
    passout = models.ManyToManyField(Passout)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254 ,null = True)
    resume = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/resume', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None , null=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('created date',auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Company(models.Model):

    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    loc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hr_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hr_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.comp_name

class Vacanccy(models.Model):

    com_name = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skillreq = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
    yearofpass = models.ManyToManyField(Passout)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    expiry_date = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.com_name)
```

[image]

the above image **1st tabel** is student , 2nd is  **company**, 3rd is **vacancy**

In Vacancy table two companies posted their requirements. The 1st company have matching profile of **rini** , also 2nd **remya**

If we filter the data and it should send to the corresponding company like **rini details to dell** and **remya details to redmi**

Comment: At first glance, you will need to use a Django HTML template to generate the email contents, then use Django's internal e-mail sending functionalities to send the generated contents.

Comment: Please, check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547/creating-email-templates-with-django

Comment: i tried that earlier  but that is not exactly i want

Comment: you have problems in `filtering or sending mail`?

Comment: i have the problem in filter and also sending email for corresponding company.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you tried to filter, and why didn't it work? What have you tried to do to send the e-mail, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a better way! but tried.
and this block of code will mail the path of the resume file, not the Actual File(you have to implement that thing).

```
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail
from django.http.response import JsonResponse


#its support function to convert queryset into dict
def get_dict_from_quryset(key, val, records):
    dict = {}
    for record in records:
        dict[record[key]] = record[val]

    return dict


def your_function_name(request):
    mail_data = []
    vacancies = Vacanccy.objects.all().values("com_name_id", "com_name__comp_name", "skillreq", "skillreq__name", "yearofpass__year")
    skills_ids = list(vacancies.values_list("skillreq", flat=True))
    comp_ids = list(set(vacancies.values_list("com_name_id", flat=True)))
    pass_years = list(vacancies.values_list("yearofpass", flat=True))
    comp_details = {}
    companies = Company.objects.filter(id__in=comp_ids).values("id","hr_email")
    dict_companies = get_dict_from_quryset("id", "hr_email", companies)
    vacancy_dict = {}
    for data in vacancies:
        vacancy_dict[data['skillreq']] = data['com_name_id']


    applicable_student_data = Student.objects.filter(skills__in=skills_ids, passout__in=pass_years).values("id","name", "resume", 'skills')

    repeat_student_id = []
    for student in applicable_student_data:
        if student['skills'] in vacancy_dict and student['id'] not in repeat_student_id:
            company_id = vacancy_dict[student['skills']]
            if company_id in dict_companies:
                email_id_hr = dict_companies[company_id]
                mail_content = ('Subject', student['resume'], 'yourrrr.from@gmail.com', [email_id_hr])
                mail_data.append(
                        mail_content
                )
                repeat_student_id.append(student['id'])
                continue

    tupple_mail_data = tuple(mail_data)

    if tupple_mail_data:
        send_mass_mail(tupple_mail_data, fail_silently=False)
    return JsonResponse({"status": "Succeed"})
```

Comment: hemal you did a great work i was trying to do this for a month means a lot

Comment: also any way to download the resumes in email

Comment: So you’re getting correct filtered data now? Have to take a look for download functionality. Not so sure

Comment: yeah working perfectly.

Comment: Try this for email with attachment https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-in-django

Comment: actually i done that part. Anyway tnx a lot